# What is the proper way to transfer a file over a network with the shutil.copy module?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, shutil

I am a novice programmer so please excuse the poor code and the simplicity of my inquiry.  I am attempting to transfer an SQL database backup from one machine to another via Python.  I am using Python version 3.6.4 on a Windows 7 Professional machine.  The machine I'm transferring it to is a Windows 10 machine.  Now, when I enter in the following code line by line in the Python shell, it works with no issue.

```
import os, pyodbc, shutil
connection = pyodbc.connect(driver = '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}',
                        server = 'SERVER',
                        database = 'DATABASE',
                        UID = 'USER',
                        PWD = 'PASS',
                        autocommit = True)
connection.cursor().execute(
    r"backup database DATABASE to disk = 'c:/DB/backup/DATABASE.bak';")
connection.close()
os.system(r'net use   \\0.0.0.001\DB\backup /user:DOMAIN\USER PASS')
os.system(r'net use   \\0.0.0.100\d\Backups /user:DOMAIN\USER PASS')
file = 'DATABASE.bak'
src = os.path.join('\\\\0.0.0.001','DB','backup', file)
dst = os.path.join('\\\\0.0.0.100','d','Backups')
shutil.move(src, dst)
os.system(r'net use * /delete /y')
```

However, when I compile the code (via pyinstaller) and run it on the Windows 10 machine, it works first the initial time and errors out each additional time.  The error I'm getting is a `Windows Error 2 (File Not Found)`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shutil.py", line 544, in move
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '\\\\0.0.0.001\\DB\\backup\\DATABASE.bak' -> '\\\\0.0.0.100\\d\\Backups\\DATABASE.bak'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transfer.py", line 47, in SQL
  File "shutil.py", line 558, in move
  File "shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
  File "shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\0.0.0.001\\DB\\backup\\DATABASE.bak'
```

I'm confused as to why this is.  Any guidance would be appreciated so I can stop banging my head on the desk.

Comment: You're using `shutil.move`. That doesn't copy a file, it moves it. Which means that, after it succeeds, the source file isn't there anymore. So if you try to move the same file again, it will fail, because you're trying to move a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: I am generating a new database backup prior to the move, so the file does exist.

Comment: The key here is: *prior to the move*. If it's there *prior to the move* then, yes, we clearly understand that. But is it then there *after the move*? Doesn't look like it!

Comment: No, if the `shutil.move` completes then the original file is removed via `os.unlink`.  When I run the script again, I start by generating the backup, mapping to the shared source directory and shared destination directory and then starting the transfer.  The old backup is manually removed prior to starting another transfer.

Comment: Ok that is fine you are saying what seems logical, but your code is NOT doing that. The file is simply not there. The error is clear. It appears you are putting the file in `c:/DB/backup/DATABASE.bak` however (!) you are looking for it in what appears to be `c:/xstoredb/backup/DATABASE.bak`... Please re-think what you are doing at a fundamental level.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry it does appear I'm pointing to the incorrect location but the original location was 'c:/xstoredb/backup'  I was just taking out the xstore bit to hide irrelevant data.  I've corrected the code.  It still does not function as intended with the correction.

Comment: Ok, a basic issue here might be that you're trying to protect sensitive data which I get; but that is confusing the real issue I think. The final two error messages now refer to IP addresses that are different (!) than the one specified in the `net use` command. One problem you're running into here now is that this is quite a departure from the original question, and you are unfortunately thus unlikely to get good help because everything has become so unclear. I think it is best if you start over with a new question that has as much of the real information as possible to avoid such problems...

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that issue.  I could simply just correct the example data again.  I did mask the IP's initially but not in the traceback.  My mistake.  I understand how that can be confusing.

Comment: if your script is ruining in same machine where the backup is done you can change the path of the backup for the absolut path to it I mean change this `src = os.path.join('\\\\0.0.0.001','DB','backup', file)` for `src = os.path.join('c:/','DB','backup', file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using `os.system()` to invoke `robocoby` then using `os.remove()` to remove the original file.  Works like a charm.  Sorry `shutil()`.